# Como enviar un valor de un input que es asignado por jquery al controller mediante Url.Action en MVC C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, webforms

Asigno un valor a un `input` mediante `jquery` en el `document ready`

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#input_1").val(“valor de prueba”);
 });
```

En el body, está el `input` e intento de enviar su valor mediante `url.action`

```
<body>
<input id=" id=”input_1" runat="server" type="text" value="" />
<a href="<%:Url.Action("Enviar","Test", new { format = "xls",dato_input = input_1.Value})%>">
                <img src="<%:Url.Content("~/Images/iconos/export_btn.png")%>" /></a>
</body>
```

Y en el controller, recibo los datos:

```
public void Enviar (string format, String dato_input)
    {
 }
```

Pero cuando llego al controller, me doy cuenta que **dato_input viene nulo**, siendo que en pantalla, el `input` tiene valor.

Me gustaría saber como enviar datos desde un `input` como parámetro a un método del controller, no se porque no funciona la forma que lo tengo

Answer (score 1):

Estas mezclando dos paradigmas distintos. Por un lado tienes un control de **ASP.NET WebForms** `<input id=" id=”input_1" runat="server" type="text" value="" />`, y por otro deseas que el valor de ese control se envíe mediante ActionLink (**etiqueta a**).

Tu etiqueta a, cuya url construyes de la siguiente forma,es incorrecta:

```
<%:Url.Action("Enviar","Test", new { format = "xls",dato_input = input_1.Value})%>
```

Debido a que a diferencia de WebForms, ASP.NET MVC no mantiene un paradigma de eventos que le permita saber cuando tu control **input_1** cambie y tenga un valor. Es por eso que si revisas el HTML generado, **dato_input** no tiene ningún valor.

Una aplicación de MVC debe ser construida bajo el paradigma de Peticion-Respuesta ([Request-Response Paradigm](https://www.w3.org/Library/User/Architecture/Request.html)), asi que tal vez desees refactorizar tu código para que luzca así:

```
<body>
<form id="enviarForm" action="<%:Url.Action("Enviar","Test", new { format = "xls"})%>">
  <input name="dato_input" type="text" value="" />

  <a href="#" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('enviarForm').submit()">
     <img src="<%:Url.Content("~/Images/iconos/export_btn.png")%>" />
  </a>
</form>
</body>
```

En este caso contruimos el HTML necesario para que al el dato sea enviado a nuestro backend (controlador), en este caso la forma mas apropiada seria un formulario. Y para mantener tu estructura de etiqueta  como botón de envio, utilizamos un poco de javascript. Si el uso de la etiqueta puede cambiarse por un botón para lograr el mismo efecto, por favor reemplazarlo por:

```
  <button type="submit">
     <img src="<%:Url.Content("~/Images/iconos/export_btn.png")%>" />
  </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

En base a lo que estoy viendo, te recomiendo obtener la variable en tu controlador mediante:

```
Request["input_1"];
```

Si andas iniciando con `ASP.net MVC` te recomiendo ver el workshop que realicé hace un par de meses: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY también revisar los cursos que hay en la [Microsoft Virtual Academy](https://mva.microsoft.com/search/SearchResults.aspx#!q=asp.net&lang=1033)